# Can't deploy java application in real host.

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I hava Java WEb application with Servlets and Jsp. 
 Bought ont host and want to deploy in the first time. And then I realize that it will be more easy to deploy Java Web Application like WAR , but my host doesn't offer this opportunity for my "Shared Tomcat".
 My jsp "index.jsp" successfully starts and then can't find my servlet. I write in web.xml, but it doesn't help.
 This is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlet.Servlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Servlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:forward page="/Servlet?action=main"></jsp:forward>
</body>
</html>
```

I have such folders in host:
-etc
-logs
-public_html
-...

[My public_html folders and files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy0kx.png). Index.jsp is here

[It's WEB_INF folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiXYZ.png). I put my servlet to 'classes', but it doesn't help. Tomcat doesn't find nothing.

Servlet in /public_html/WEB_INF/classes/servlet/Servlet.java

I've tried make 'src' folder in the root directory, but it won't help. 
And I want to know how to start my java application? I need to "index.jsp" find my servlet succesffull and servlet other *.java . 
Hosting have "Tomcat 5" and can't work with WAR.
Thanks for anwers

Comment: Have you restarted Tomcat after putting your classes into WEB-INF folder? jsp's are compiled on the fly, but the WEB-INF classes are loaded only on start.

Comment: I've done already. Doesn't help. Other project structure is right, you think?

Comment: Wait a minute, you need to compile your classes. If you just put your source code (i.e. *.java) into WEB-INF it won't be compiled. Compile your classes and put (*.class) instead of (*.java)

Comment: Your host won't accept WAR files? Then get a better host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should put in the /public_html/WEB_INF/classes/servlet/ folder is not your Servlet.java, it's your **Servlet.class**.

Comment: Thanks a lot, help for me.